# Perl: rsync with 'ssh -q' fails with exit code 14

Tags: perl, rsync, quoting

I need to run an rsync task from a perl script. (The code below is part of a larger script and using perl is unavoidable.) Since rsync is being run noninteractively, I'd like to avoid printing the ssh login banner from the server I'm uploading files to. I have seen that using the command `rsync -e 'ssh -q'` is the way to do this, and **this works from the command line**. (Well, I'm using the long option format `--rsh='ssh -q'` for readability in the script.)

However, I cannot seem to get this to work from my perl script. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $src = '/path/to/myfile';
my $dest = 'remote:/path/to/target';

my @rsync_cmd;

# this one works, returns 0
@rsync_cmd = ('rsync', '--archive', '--update', '--rsh=ssh', $src, $dest);
system(@rsync_cmd);
print "Exit code: ", $? >> 8, "\n\n";

# this one doesn't, returns 14
@rsync_cmd = ('rsync', '--archive', '--update', '--rsh=\'ssh -q\'', $src, $dest);
system(@rsync_cmd);
print "Exit code: ", $? >> 8;
```

The first command works fine and returns 0. The second command returns 14 (Error in IPC code) and gives the following output:

```
rsync: Failed to exec ssh -q: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [sender=3.1.1]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

As I said, however, running rsync with `--rsh='ssh -q'` from the command line does work fine, so I'm not sure what's going on here. I've tried various other ways of quoting the ssh command:

- `'--rsh="ssh -q"'`
- `q{--rsh='ssh -q'}`
- `q{--rsh="ssh -q"}`

(plus a few more) and all of these give the same exit code (14).

Other things I've tried with no success:

- Replacing `ssh` with `/usr/bin/ssh` in case rsync was having trouble finding the ssh binary.
- Using short option format `-e 'ssh -q'`.
- Using [File::Rsync](http://search.cpan.org/~leakin/File-Rsync/Rsync.pm) module (perl wrapper for rsync) to try to avoid quoting problems.
- Setting the `RSYNC_RSH` environment variable via `$ENV{'RSYNC_RSH'}=q{ssh -q}`.
- Removing the `--archive` and `--update` options for testing purposes.

All of these result in the same exit code, 14. I am at my wits' end, please help.

Comment: You can try with [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH) using its [rsync_put](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#$ssh-%3Ersync_put(\%opts,-$local1,-$local2,...,-$remote_dir_or_file)) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system(..., "--rsh=ssh -q", ...)`

You are using the `system LIST` syntax, which already passes each argument uninterpolated to the called program. `"--rsh=ssh -q"` from Perl is equivalent to `--rsh='ssh -q'` in the shell. The quotes will treat the `ssh` and the `-q` as part of the same argument to the command, but the quotes themselves will be interpolated away in the shell, so `rsync` will receive the argument as `--rsh=ssh -q`.